# Как проверить элементы матрицы на уникальность

Tags: c++

```
void introduction_matrix(double **arr, int rows, int cols)
{
    int tmp; 
    bool flag;
    cout << "Введите [0][0] элемент матрицы => ";
    cin >> arr[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < cols; j++)
        {
            flag = true;
            do {
                cout << "Введите [" << i << "][" << j << "] элемент матрицы => ";
                while (!(cin >> tmp || (cin.peek() != '\n')))
                {
                    cin.clear();
                    while (cin.get() != '\n');
                    cout << "Ошибка! Поворите попытку: ";
                }
                for (int i1 = 0; i1 < i; i1++)
                {
                    for (int j1 = 0; j1 < j; j1++)
                    {
                        if (arr[i1][j1] == tmp)
                        {
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } while (!flag);
            arr[i][j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Не работает проверка.

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов использовать множество (`std::set`):

```
void introduction_matrix(double **arr, int rows, int cols)
{
    int tmp; 
    bool flag;
    std::set<int> uniqueValues;
    cout << "Введите [0][0] элемент матрицы => ";
    cin >> arr[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < cols; j++)
        {
            flag = true;
            do {
                cout << "Введите [" << i << "][" << j << "] элемент матрицы => ";
                while (!(cin >> tmp || (cin.peek() != '\n')))
                {
                    cin.clear();
                    while (cin.get() != '\n');
                    cout << "Ошибка! Поворите попытку: ";
                }

               if (uniqueValues.count(tmp) == 0){
                   uniqueValues.insert(tmp);
                   arr[i][j] = tmp;
                   flag = true;
               }else{
                  flag = false;
               }
            } while (!flag);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое) а если пользоваться коллекциями нельзя, без них никак нельзя?((((

Comment: Можно. я не запускал, но у Вас при проверке не проверяется текущая строка, а только предыдущая. То есть если Вы начнёте вводить первую строку, введёте в первый столбец 1, а потом попытаетесь ввести во второй столбец снова единицу, то в цикл проверки вообще не зайдёте. @Trapezant